# How to compute P values for Breusch pagan test?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, breusch-pagan

I got bptest() output for my OLS model as follows;

```
studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  modelfit
BP = 3.3201, df = 3, p-value = 0.3449
```

I read that BP test is an F test of squared residuals and independent variables. There are 40 records and 3 independent variables in the data.

My question is, is the test statistic in the R output the F test statistic of the auxiliary equation. How do I compute the p-value?

Comment: The function documentation says it uses a chi-square distributed statistic.  I would assume *BP*, *df*, and *p-value* in the output would follow this description.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Ok. I think BP test does an LM test. But can we use this F value as a measure of heteroscedasticity?

Comment: I don't know (and I'm still not sure where the F statistic is you're referring to). It might make sense to take the BP test statistic and divide by the sample size. From what I read, this would be the r-square from the auxiliary regression. I haven't seen this, but it's reasonably easy to explain to a reader.

Comment: @SalMangiafico The F value of the regression between squared error and independent vars. It is significant then there is heteroscedasticity. I saw this in a youtube video

Comment: I suppose there would be some way to use the F as a measure of heteroscedasticity, but without a reference using it in this way, you'd have to worry about how the degrees of freedom for the F affect its use as a "measure of heteroscedasticity".  I think you are are better off using something analogous to an effect size statistic, in this case the BP statistic standardized by the sample size.  This is the r-square from the auxiliary equation.  This, along with the p-value from the BP test, I think this tells the story.  I'll turn this suggestion into an answer later.

Comment: I think I just understood the question.  You don't do anything with the F value from auxiliary regression.  It would be like trying to re-invent a statistical test that already exists.  The p-value reported by `bptest` is the p-value you want.  The YouTube video you are looking at may be explaining the essence of the test, but the test doesn't deal with that F value directly.  The test calculates a BP statistic, which is chi-square distributed, and so uses a chi-square test.

Comment: What confused me is the phrase "measure of heteroscedasticity".  I thought you were looking for something analogous to an effect size statistic for the test.  In any case, be sure to understand what a p-value indicates.  And that it is not a measure of the amount of heteroscedasticity.  It provides the degree of evidence against the null hypothesis (no heteroscedasticity).

Comment: @SalMangiafico ok. I think "measure of heteroscedasticity" was a wrong choice of words.

Comment: No worries.  I'll clean up these comments and add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, I think I have the import of the question.

The simple answer is that, for the significance test for the Breusch-Pagan test, the F value from the auxiliary regression doesn't need to be addressed at all.  Instead, the test develops a statistic (*BP* below), which, by my understanding, is chi-square distributed.  So the test uses a chi-square test and reports a p-value.

The following R uses the *lmtest* package, and uses a studentized version of the test.  This is the default for the `bptest` function.  My understanding is that this form of the test is more robust than the original version [citation needed].

```
if(!require(lmtest)){install.packages("lmtest")}
library(lmtest)

A = 1:10
B = 1:100
C = 1:1000

Value = c(A, B, C)
Group = factor(c(rep("A", length(A)), 
                 rep("B", length(B)), 
                         rep("C", length(C))))

Model = lm(Value ~ Group)

BPTest = bptest(Model)

BPTest

   ###  studentized Breusch-Pagan test
   ###
   ### data:  Model
   ### BP = 120.37, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I had thought the question was asking about developing a statistic analogous to an effect size statistic for the BP test.  I don't have any citation, but I thought using the *BP* statistic divided by the sample size --- which should be equivalent to the r-squared for the auxiliary regression under some versions of the test --- might make sense.

```
BP = BPTest$statistic

n  = length(residuals(Model))

rSquaredBP = BP / n

names(rSquaredBP) = "rSquaredBP"

rSquaredBP

   ### rSquaredBP 
   ###  0.1084405
```

This is equivalent to the r-squared for the auxiliary regression under some versions of the test.

```
Res = residuals(Model)^2

Model2 = lm(Res ~ Group)

summary(Model2)$r.squared

   ### [1] 0.1084405
```

It appears that this matches the studentized version of the test, but not others.  For example compare `bptest(Model, studentize=F)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer